# pyside6 6.6.2 When using QAudioOutput, the program will freeze when switching to the next video

Tags: pyside6, qmediaplayer

pyside6 6.6.2 Use QMediaPlayer to play video, if using QAudioOutput, the program will freeze when switching to the next video but don't use QAudioOutput, that is ok

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0woI.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh7CW.png)

[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGo0t.png)

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and  s screenshot.